# Destructure nested object with defaults, including nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

With ECMAScript 6, I can write this:

```
const {
  a = mandatory('a'),
  b: {
    c = mandatory('c'),
    d = mandatory('d')
  } = mandatory('b')
} = { a: 'a', b: { c: 'c', d: 'd' } }
console.log(a, b, c, d)

function mandatory (field) {
  throw new Error(`Not giving you a ReferenceError today, but you must set a non-falsy value to "${field}"!`)
}
```

`mandatory` is a function that utilizes the "defaults syntax" and intends throw a "known" error in case a property is set to a falsy value.

When I run the code, I get a `ReferenceError: b is not defined`. If I remove `d: 'd'` it suddenly does not throw the error anymore.

```
... = { a: 'a', b: { c: 'c' } }
```

It throws a **desired** error:

```
Error: Not giving you a ReferenceError today, but you must set a non-falsy value "d"!
```

1. How can I make `b` defined?
2. How can I call `mandatory` and throw my own error if `a.b` is set to a non-falsy value?

Comment: *If I remove `d: 'd'`* - from where? That's not in the code you posted.

Comment: And your code as-is works fine for me in Node 6.2.2.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. I added ```d: 'd'```. So the "ReferenceError" is not desired, but the "Error" is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Actually, it does not make sense for me to have a `mandatory` function call in case `b` has a falsy value. If `c` or `d`do exist, `b` will be non-falsy.

But to make `b` defined for further proessing, it is can be done like this:

```
const {
  a = mandatory('a'),
  b, // Added this line
  b: {
    c = mandatory('c'),
    d = mandatory('d')
  }
} = { a: 'a', b: { c: 'c', d: 'd'} }
console.log(a, b, c, d)

function mandatory (field) {
  throw new Error(`Not giving you a ReferenceError today, but you must set "${field}"!`)
}
```

This no longer gives the reference error.

Answer (score 0):

`b` is not defined because there's no such variable. The `b:` only is the property name for the value that gets assigned to the destructuring object literal, it does not declare a variable `b`. To get one, you'll need to use two destructuring steps:

```
const {
  a = mandatory('a'),
  b = mandatory('b'),
} = { a: 'a', b: { c: 'c', d: 'd' } },
// or write `; const` here           ^
{
  c = mandatory('b.c'),
  d = mandatory('b.d')
} = b;
console.log(a, b, c, d);
```

Comment: ? his code worked fine for me in the Firefox console

Comment: @Pointy Ah, I missed the answer that uses a duplicate property name.